# SQL: Need advice on how to write this SQL

Tags: sql

ASSLIB ( Asset & Liabilities records)
REVEXP ( Revenu & Expense records has a FK ASSLIB_ID from ASSLIB)

PERXRVEX ( Relationship between PERSON , REVEXP table joined ON REVEXP_ID)
PERXASLB ( Relationship between PERSON , ASSLIB table joined ON ASSLIB_ID)

Normally, all REVEXP, owned by a PERSON ( in PERXRVEX),  which is linked to an ASSLIB .. The latter (ASSLIB) should also appear in PERXASLB as well. If not it is an exception.

I need a way to find me all exception records, show me the ASSLIB_ID and PERSON_ID with the following:

```
Example:
PERSON - PERSON_ID
P1 John
P2 Jane

ASSLIB - ASSLIB_ID
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5

REVEXP - REVEXP_ID | ASSLIB_ID (FK)
E1 | A1
E2 | A2
E8 | NULL
E9 | NULL

PERXASLB - PERSON_ID | ASSLIB_ID
P1 | A1
P1 | A2
P1 | A3
P1 | A4
P2 | A5



PERXRVEX - PERSON_ID | REVEXP_ID
P1 | E1
P1 | E2
P1 | E8
P2 | E1 ===> Exception to show in my report as E1 has parent A1 based on REVEXP but P2 does not have A1 based on PERXASLB
P2 | E2 ===> Exception to show in my report as E2 has parent A2 based on REVEXP but P2 does not have A2
P2 | E9
```

Comment: I don't understand what makes your exceptions. A3\A4 are linked to E1\E2 and also P2. In PERXREVEX P2 for E1\E2 exists therefore they are not an exception. P1 for E3\E4 is not an exception because it hasn't been assigned in PERXASLB ? P1 for E1\E2 is an exception because E1 and E2 have already been allocated to a person from PERXASLB?? Confused! please can you be more clear what determines whether its an exception!??

Comment: Sorry ... i messed up my example while trying to simplify my problem... I've corrected it

Comment: My advice, is to rename your tables to things that are readable in english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like ?

```
Select * 
from PERXRVEX px
INNER JOIN REVEXP rp on rp.REVEXP_ID = px.REVEXP_ID
LEFT JOIN PERXASLB pb on pb.PERSON_ID = px.PERSON_ID
                     AND pb.ASSLIB_ID= rp.ASSLIB_ID
WHERE pb.ASSLIB_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: I think this may be it...I can understand my request may not be very clear but i think you pulled it off. Thanks. I was using one with EXCEPT and it seemed complicated...